# Properties of UILabel on UIViewController on UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, subview

Consider the following situation:
I have this myViewcontroller. On the Storyboard I have added a UIViewController, defined it as a myViewcontroller, with a couple of UILabels on them. I have properly connected them to the IBOutlets.

Then, I have a scrollview. I add instances of myViewcontroller to that scrollview as such:

```
- (void)configureInfoViewController
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [Lists count]; i++) {
        myViewcontroller *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myLabelLayout"];
        [self addChildViewController:vc];
    }
}

- (void)configureScrollView
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.childViewControllers count]; i++) {
        CGRect frame = theScrollView.frame;
        ...
        [[[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:i] view] setFrame:frame];
        [theScrollView addSubview:[[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:i] view]];
    }
}
```

So, I have as many subviews in theScrollview as there are objects in Lists. So far so good.
But now, I want to set the text of a label in one of these subviews. I want to accomplish that by pushing a UIButton on that very same instance of that myViewcontroller.

The question is: how do I set that myLable.title?
I hope this makes sense.

---

I think the REAL question is, that bothers me:
How do I know on what subview my UIButton resides. I could then send that metadata to other methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have created outlets for your labels and when you push the button can't you just access the label and change its text in the button's IBAction method?

Here is what you need,

```
#import "MyViewcontroller.h"

@implementation MyViewcontroller

- (IBAction)myButtonAction:(id)sender {
    _myLabel.text = @"My custom value";
}

@end
```

FYI, your InfoViewController your configureScrollView method should be like this. I don't see your scroll view content size adjusted in your code.

```
- (void)configureScrollView {
    for (int i=0; i<self.childViewControllers.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame = theScrollView.frame;
        // scrolling vertically here
        frame.origin.y = CGRectGetHeight(frame) * i;

        UIView *view = [[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:i] view];
        [view setFrame:frame];
        [theScrollView addSubview:view];
    }

    theScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(theScrollView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(theScrollView.frame) * self.childViewControllers.count);
}
```

Comment: That is the correct assumption. I think the simplified question would be: How do I know on which subview my UIButton resides? If I would know that, I would be able to pass on the ID throughout my methods. I will update my question.

Comment: So you have only one button for all view controllers or one button for each view controller?

Comment: I have a button on each viewcontroller. The button obviously is triggering the same method in each instance of the viewcontroller.

Comment: @Sjakelien The above solution works, The scope of label is available in the button's action and you can change its text.